# pandas add column to dataframe having the value from another row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe with columns named 'id', 'x', 'y', and 'time'

| id | time | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 14 | 12 |
| 1 | 1 | 32 | 23 |
| 1 | 2 | 52 | 14 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 | 34 |
| 3 | 0 | 62 | 17 |
| 3 | 1 | 82 | 35 |
| 3 | 2 | 22 | 25 |

I want to add two columns to the dataframe so that they have the value of x and y from another row having the same id and a time + 2

the result should like this:

| id | time | x | y | x2 | y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 14 | 12 | 52 | 14 |
| 1 | 1 | 32 | 23 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 52 | 14 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 12 | 34 |  |  |
| 3 | 0 | 62 | 17 | 22 | 25 |
| 3 | 1 | 82 | 35 |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 22 | 25 |  |  |

please note that the dataframe is not sorted by id

I have tried the following for x2 but it is not working as intended:

```
t=2
data['x2'] = data.apply(lambda x: x['x'] if (data[(data['id']==x['id']) & ((data['time']+t) == x['time'])].size > 0) else '', axis=1)
```

The following works but I need to use a shortcut way and the one with the best performance because my data is huge

```
t=2
for index, row in data.iterrows():    
    rowT = data[(data['id']==row['id']) & (data['time'] == (row['time'] + t))]
    if rowT.size > 0:
      data.loc[index,'x2'] = rowT['x'].values[0]
```

Comment: Are all the values in `time` column present sequentially per `id`?

Comment: time =0  and time+2=2 there are three results: (52,14),(12,34),(22,55) how did the second occurrence of time=2 select (22,55)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma No they are not. Also, not all ids have all the time values. It needs to be solved by condition

Comment: @GoldenLion they need to be of the same id.

Comment: when is 12,34 selected? reveal the rules to the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe by repopulating the values in `time` column with the values at `t-2` seconds, then **left** `merge` this new dataframe with the original dataframe on the columns `id, time` to get the result:

```
df_r = df.assign(time=df['time'].sub(2))
df.merge(df_r, on=['id', 'time'], how='left', suffixes=['', '2'])
```

---

```
   id  time   x   y    x2    y2
0   1     0  14  12  52.0  14.0
1   1     1  32  23   NaN   NaN
2   1     2  52  14   NaN   NaN
3   2     2  12  34   NaN   NaN
4   3     0  62  17  22.0  25.0
5   3     1  82  35   NaN   NaN
6   3     2  22  25   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: I only faced one problem because the actual dataframe has other columns so the solution, in this case, gives additional unneeded columns. I simply dropped them. I am not sure if the merge statement can be modified to select specific columns to merge. Anyway, dropping them gives the intended results

Answer (score 0):

look up time +2 within each id

```
id=[1,1,1,2,3,3,3]
time=[0,1,2,2,0,1,2]
x=[14,32,52,12,62,82,22]
y=[12,23,14,34,17,35,25]

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':id,'time':time,'x':x,'y':y})
df.reset_index()
df['x2']=0
df['y2']=0

for key,item in df.iterrows():

   lookup=(item['time']+2) 
   filter=(df['time']==lookup) & (df['id']==item['id'])
   results=df[filter]
   if len(results)>0:
       row=results.iloc[0]
       x2=row.x
       y2=row.y
       df.loc[key,['x2','y2']]=(x2,y2)


print(df) 

output:
   id  time   x   y  x2  y2
0   1     0  14  12  52  14
1   1     1  32  23   0   0
2   1     2  52  14   0   0
3   2     2  12  34   0   0
4   3     0  62  17  22  25
5   3     1  82  35   0   0
6   3     2  22  25   0   0

#no looping
df2=df.copy()
df2['time'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x['time']+2, axis=1)
results=df2[['id','time','x','y']].merge(df[['id','time','x','y']]
,on=['id','time'],how="left",suffixes=('', '2')).fillna(0)
print(results)
```

Comment: I fixed a bug so reconsider your vote.  The code is working now.

Comment: I am asking for a shortcut solution using lambda for example and not a loop. I've mentioned in the question that it is working for me using the loop but not with a shortcut way.

Comment: did you run %%timeit  to which solution performed best?  my solution could be changed to a list comprehension that calls a function but that is syntax sugar.